# Propagating client details for remote EJB invocations from standalone Java client

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.1

I am looking for a way to propagate client details (like application name, host name, tenant, etc) from a standalone client that is looking up and invoking remote EJBs on a Weblogic 12c server.

I am familiar with similar capabilities in JBoss (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBCLIENT-61) that allow me to register a interceptor and pass additional metadata in the invocation context.

Is there a similar API for WebLogic?

Any pointers, alternatives much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to do the exact same kind of thing in Weblogic. Check here fo a sample interceptor. http://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2009/07/programming-annotated-ejb-3.html This thread will probably also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608349/using-ejbcontext-getcontextdata-is-this-safe

Comment: Thanks but I need to propagate info from a standalone Java client to WLS. JBoss lets me register a interceptor on the client side (in my standalone client) and add data that I can access on the server side in the invocation context.