# Access the context properties from EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, qualifiers

I have a test client of an EJB service

```
    Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "my_user");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "my_secret");
    jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
    jndiProperties.put("TEST_STRING", "ABC");

    Context jndi = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    ...
    productService = (ServiceRemote) jndi.lookup(moduleName + "/" + beanName + "!" + className);
```

I can successfully test the methods of productService class via this command line test class.

The problem I am trying to solve is to pass TEST_STRING in the context and read it on EJB side in order to inject different Dao for testing purposes only (qualifier).

I don't know how to access context parameters from EJB class.

Or if there is another way to "suggest" which Qualifier to use ... I am all ears :)

Thank you

Comment: do you use junit? mock the dependencies on setup. some information about `EJBContext` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608349/using-ejbcontext-getcontextdata-is-this-safe

Comment: Are you using JPA?

Comment: yes, my EBJ uses JPA and wildfly is providing the datasource